# Opensource library similar to avahi

Tags: open-source, bonjour, avahi

I need to write an application on windows that connects to avahi running on Linux.I need opensource tools that i can use on windows os.
Im aware of BONJOUR.But it is tied to apple licenses...
Im not aware of tools.Can somebody suggest something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Bonjour is not tied to any Apple licenses as stated on [this official webpage](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/). Instead Apple has released it under the Open Source Apache 2.0 license. This allows you to view the source code and also link against it in your own open source project.